# Catch error with $.post using $.ajaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to catch the "**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**" error when i do **$.post**.

My jquery $.post code is:

```
        $.post( "parseRequest", { request: "myFile.xml" }, function( data ) {
            //do something with json data
        }, "json");
```

Sometimes, if the file doesn't exist for example, the server will send back a blank response. I'll receive this on the client side:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/parseRequest net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Is there a way to catch this?

I tried using .ajaxError(), but am not using it right... this is what I tried:

```
        $.post( "parseRequest", { request: "myFile.xml" }, function( data ) {
            //do something with json data
        }, "json").ajaxError(function() {
            console.log( "** Triggered ajaxError handler." );
        });
```

But I get a 'function undefined' error when i try this.

I'm using jquery 1.11.1

Relevant pages:

- $.post: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- $.ajaxError: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: `ajaxError` is a global handler for all ajax calls, is that what you want, if so it has to be applied on the document level? It looks more like you just want to replace `ajaxError` with `fail` ?

Comment: I think by the way she is using ajax she would be better off using the error callback. so replace ajaxError with error. i could be wrong but it is worth a try.

Comment: "error" didn't catch the error :/ and "fail" made $.post fail :( The server would give no response and halt x.x I'll keep experimenting